# repeat xml data into a div

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a function which retrieve data from a xml file and then it is supposed to show it in a div. The problem is that I only get the last element of the array. Is there a way to obtain all the elements and populate them into the div?

Here is the function:

```
 function paradascamionesHistorico() {
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
infowindowMarkerParadas.close();
});
var Boton = document.getElementById('Boton').value;
var textboxImei = document.getElementById('imeiHistorico').value;
var textboxFecha = document.getElementById('fechaInicioHistorico').value;
var textboxFechaFin = document.getElementById('fechaFinHistorico').value;
var textboxDesdeHora = document.getElementById('desdeHoraHistorico').value;
var textboxHastaHora = document.getElementById('hastaHoraHistorico').value;

downloadUrl("paradas.asp?imei="+textboxImei+"&fecha="+textboxFecha+" "+textboxDesdeHora+"&fechaFin="+textboxFechaFin+" "+textboxHastaHora, 
function(data) {
    var xml = xmlParse(data);
    var markersParadas = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");    
    var position = [];
    //var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 

    for (var i = 0; i < markersParadas.length; i++) {

    var lat = parseFloat(markersParadas[i].getAttribute("lat"));
    var lng = parseFloat(markersParadas[i].getAttribute("lng"));
    var myLatlngParadas = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    var fechaInicio = markersParadas[i].getAttribute("fechaInicio");
    var fechaFinal = markersParadas[i].getAttribute("fechaFinal");
    var diferencia = markersParadas[i].getAttribute("diferencia");
    //alert(+diferencia);

    var datearray = diferencia.split("/"); 

    var newDate = datearray[1] + '/' + datearray[0] + '/' + datearray[2];
    var aFecha = new Date(newDate);
        var hours = aFecha.getHours();
        var minutes = aFecha.getMinutes();
        var seconds = aFecha.getSeconds();

    var markerParadas = createMarkerParadas(myLatlngParadas, hours, minutes, seconds, fechaInicio, fechaFinal);

    myMarkersParadas.push(markerParadas);
    var tablaParadas = '<a href="javascript:myclickParadas(' + (myMarkersParadas.length-1) + ')">' + seconds + '<\/a><br>';


 document.getElementById("paradasDiv").innerHTML = tablaParadas;
  }//finish loop




}); //end download url

}//termina function


function myclickParadas(i) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(myMarkersParadas[i], "click");
  }
```

So if anyone knows how to show the rest of the elements of the array I will be very gratefully.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById("paradasDiv").innerHTML = tablaParadas;`
You are overwriting `innerHTML` of `#paradasDiv` on each iteration of your loop.
That's why you only see the last element of the array.

You have to append to it:
`document.getElementById("paradasDiv").innerHTML += tablaParadas;`

Also, before starting the loop you maybe need to empty it:

`document.getElementById("paradasDiv").innerHTML = '';`